# Clip geodatabase containing vector and raster data

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, geoprocessing, clip, file-geodatabase

I have a fairly large file geodatabase in ArcGIS 10.1 containing **both vector and raster datasets**. Generally, I only want to work on a small extent at a time. Is it possible to clip a geodatabase to a smaller extent to reduce its size on disk?

Comment: Sure, it's possible.  But how do you define "clip" with respect to vectors?  Do you want whole features that overlap your study area (as in a selection set) or do you want the features' boundaries truncated at your working window, as provided by Clip (Analysis)?  http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//000800000004000000

Comment: Also, are you talking about a rectangular extent or any polygon being used as the "clipping" area?

Comment: Yes clipped using a rectangular extent, truncating all features at the study area boundary :)

Answer (score 1):

[Esri Forum Post](http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/18113-clip-geodatabase)

There's a post about it from June 2013. Andy writes:

> At least with ArcMap 10.1 Advanced licence, the clip tool only accepts feature classes as inputs not [file] geodatabases (or feature datasets), so this won't work for people in many cases. I suspect that other licences/products (ArcMap on Server?) may do the above.
>
> It is still pretty tedious to set up, but you can right click on the clip tool and select batch, and then create a row for each feature class you want to clip (need to create the new target geodatabase first). The "input features" browser will multi-select feature classes which helps.
>
> Andy.

I thought about geoprocessing environment ['Output Extent'](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Output_Extent/001w00000009000000/), but that does not clip, rather processes features that pass within the extent.